# Are there any cave systems generated in Minecraft Pocket Edition?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I've been playing the mobile version of Minecraft for a few days now, and have yet to see an underground cave system. Are there any generated with the terrain, or is it all solid ground?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've spent the better part of an hour now searching for a source to confirm my answer, but I can't find anything. However with that said:

It's based on Minecraft Classic, so I doubt there would be, especially considering the world has an end just like the original Minecraft Classic on PC (on which there are no caves).

Add that to the fact that I'm yet to come across a cave system as well and I'm pretty sure there aren't any.

Comment: The game mode on desktop Minecraft doesn't affect world generation. Why do you think it would on Pocket Edition?

Comment: @KevinReid I actually meant the original creative mode (the one that came out before survival and is played on the web), not the one in the actual game.

Comment: For the record, the "original creative mode" is mostly referred to as "Minecraft Classic".

Answer (score 2):

There are some seeds that you can use to simulate "caves" – they're not actual generated caves, more like base-less mountains or deep overhangs. Three I know are `Infinity`, `Nyan` and `Waterworld`, but there are lots more.

Comment: Also: Doviikin jpgaming garbage truck

Comment: What about the free version?? I have seen cave like overhangs before, and one had a waterfall in it.

Answer (score 1):

I know some cave seeds, such as "BBB", "thegobsofbog", and "nyan". Most worlds have a chance of having caves though; just mine it out a lot.

Answer (score 0):

They are adding caves in 0.9.0 so currently there are no caves
But you can get big overhangs which look like caves i have a seed with it and here's the 
Seed-3939373 
And here's a screenshot
[image]